# Get similarity percent with sklearn hashing vectorizer

Tags: python, scikit-learn, vectorization

I have python program, that fetch article from few sites and store them on database, in my case, when I wan't add new article in database, I should check it's not a duplicate article. I want do this work simply with get percent of similarity and setting a threshold for it(for example, i say if (percent of similarity two string) > 70% then new article is duplicate)

My problem is finding percent of similarity. now I use [difflib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html) and SequenceMatcher class:

```
diff = SequenceMatcher(
   None, article1.content, article2.content).ratio()
```

But it 's not right and I think using [HashingVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.HashingVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.HashingVectorizer) is better for this case(?):

```
vectorizer = HashingVectorizer(n_features=(2**18))
article1_vector = vectorizer.transform([article1.content])
article2_vector = vectorizer.transform([article2.content])
```

How can I get percent of similarity two hashvector(for example cosine distance) and how can I convert it to percent? thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the default settings for `HashingVectorizer` (in particular, `norm="l2"`), the cosine similarity between these two vectors is

```
sim = (article1_vector * article2_vector.T).A[0, 0]
```

This is really just a dot product with some trickery to get rid of the SciPy sparse matrix format.

This gives a similarity between `-1` and `1`, so you could add one and divide by two to get a percentage.